# Get count of all tweets till given date

Tags: php, json, twitter

i have tried the following code to get count to all tweets. but now i want to get count of all tweets till given date. i am using following code to get count of tweets till given date, but it always returns me all tweet till today instead of till given date.how is this possible to get tweets till given date.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$userdata = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" . $twitteruser."&until:2016-01-01");
```

And when i use the following code it gives me always latest 20 tweets instead of changing the date, There are total 36 tweet in my account.

```
$userdata = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" . $twitteruser . "&until:2016-01-01");
```